# How to postmapping in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have 5 `models:`

1. `admin`
2. `food`
3. `orders`
4. `payments`
5. `users`

`admin` - admin can view/add/edit/delete `food`, and getting all `users` data(this part is done).
`users` - users can create orders.

so by my understanding, I did the mapping as follows:

1. `users`(1)-->`orders`(M)
2. `orders`(1)-->`food`(M)
3. `orders`(1)-->`payments`(1)

here is my code for all entity.

```java
public class Users {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long usersId;
    
    @Column(name="user_fName")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="user_lName")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="user_email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="user_password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name="user_phnNumber")
    private String phNumber;
    
    @Column(name="user_address")
    private String address;
    
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy= "users")
    private Set<Orders> order;
}
```

```java
public class Payments {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    
    @Column(name="payment_id")
    private Long paymentId;
    
    @Column(name="payment_amount")
    private Long paymentAmount;
    
    @Column(name="payment_date")
    private Date paymentDate;
    
    @Column(name="payment_transactionId")
    private Long paymentTransactionId;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    Orders orders;

    public Payments(Long paymentAmount, Date paymentDate, Long paymentTransactionId,Orders orders1) {
        super();
        this.paymentAmount = paymentAmount;
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
        this.paymentTransactionId = paymentTransactionId;
        this.orders = orders1;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    
    @Column(name="order_id")
    private Long orderId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    Users users;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Food> food;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Payments payments;
    
    @Column(name="order_quantity")
    private Long orderQuantity;
    
    @Column(name="order_date")
    private Date orderDate;
    
    @Column(name="order_status")
    private Boolean orderStatus;

    public Orders(Long orderQuantity, Date orderDate, Boolean orderStatus,Users users1) {
        super();
        this.orderQuantity = orderQuantity;
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
        this.users = users1;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Food {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="food_sequence",
            sequenceName="food_sequence",
            allocationSize=1
            )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator="food_sequence"
            )
    
    @Column(name="food_id")
    private Long foodId;
    
    @Column(name="food_name")
    private String foodName;
    
    @Column(name="food_desc")
    private String foodDesc;
    
    @Column(name="food_price")
    private String foodPrice;
    
    @Column(name="food_status")
    private Boolean foodStatus;
    
    @Column(name="food_img")
    private String foodImg;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orders_id")
    Orders orders;

    public Food(String foodName, 
            String foodDesc, 
            String foodPrice, 
            Boolean foodStatus,
            String foodImg,
            Orders order1
            ) {
        super();
        this.foodName = foodName;
        this.foodDesc = foodDesc;
        this.foodPrice = foodPrice;
        this.foodStatus = foodStatus;
        this.foodImg = foodImg;
        this.orders = order1;
    }
}
```

**So my Question:** how to create an order. and when I see `food` table it has column `orders_id`. but here first admin will add food and then in the users side user will create orders using those food.
I am stuck at creating an order.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to remove the Payments column in the Orders class and the Orders column in the Food class.

Every order has a Payment, and you already do this by joining Order inside the Payments class. Likewise, there can be more than one Food in an Order, and you do this inside the Orders class.

To create an order, as you said, first the admin needs to add food to the table. After the food data is added to the table, the user will select food to create an order and you will add the selected food to the Order object's food attribute.(*This could be better btw*)

Then you will create a Payment with the Order that you created and manage the Payment separately.